# Receiving HTTP 429 from Azure Text-to-Speech, despite very low usage

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, quota, http-status-code-429

I am using Azure Text-to-Speech services with a Standard Plan (S0), to generate speech from text input.
From time to time, 1 request receive a 429 response from Azure, despite very low usage. Very low usage means I am way below the quota of 200 transactions per second stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/ai-services/speech-service/speech-services-quotas-and-limits?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_ProjectOxford#real-time-text-to-speech), I am around 10 transactions per minute.

But on my Azure admin panel, I can see a lot of quota limits. Most of them are irrelevant, but some of them looks related to text to speech

To generate a text-to-speech, i'm hitting the endpoint https://westeurope.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1 and i'm using Neural voices. Is there a specific quota I should be aware of in the following ones ?

- Token (50 tps)
- speech Synthesize (200 tps)
- speech Neuralvoicesynthesize (200 tps)
- speech texttospeech (10 tps)